# Problems with .Rnw files and chunks in R

Tags: r, latex, rnw

I am new to R and I made a rnw-file in R-Studio to create a PDF file for MikTex. The file consists of Latex-Code as well as R-Code in chunks and it has worked well before. Yesterday, I updated some packages and R-Studio and now I am getting a generell error. Even after searching for a longer time online, I couldn´t find a solution. For example, my first line starts with `\documentclass{article}` and I get the error "*unexpected input in "\"*. Even when I open a totally new R-Sweave file (.Rnw) starting with `\documentclass{article}` it gives me the same error with the unexpected input.

The same, when I insert a chunk with R-Code starting with `<<>>=`, then it brings the same error "*unexpected input in* "<<" ".

Has anybody an idea, what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Any particular reason why you’re using Rnw? It’s been pretty much replaced by modern technologies, in particular knitr and RMarkdown.

Comment: Great advise. I shiftet to RMarkdown and get the PDF by knitr... and it worked. The code is working and another plus: With Sweave the graphic wasn´t included into the PDF, but now it is exactly where I wanted it to be. Thank you very much!